# Determine when the system has a) no solution, b) 1 solution and c) infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

This question is not for an assignment, it was on the midterm and I am interested in figuring out how to solve it before the final exam.

cheers,

Determine when the system has a) no solution, b) 1 solution and c) infinitely many solutions
Given the system
\begin{align*}
x + y + 7z & = -7\\
2x + 3y +17z & = -16\\
x +2y +(a^2+1)z & = 3a
\end{align*}

Attempted Solution

using matrix form $$\pmatrix{1&1&7&-7\cr2&3&17&-16\cr1&2&a^2+1&3a\cr}$$ using gaussian elimination to isolate eqn 3 for variable z (sorry about the missing a^2+1 up there html doesn't like me)

line 1 - line 3

$$\pmatrix{1&1&7&-7\cr2&3&17&-16\cr 0&1&7-(a^2+1)&-7-3a\cr}$$

2*line 1 - line 2

$$\pmatrix{1&1&7&-7\cr 0&-1&-3&2 \cr 0&-1&7-(a^2+1)&-7-3a\cr}$$

-1*line2

$$\pmatrix{1 & 1 &7 &-7\\ 0 & 1 & 3 & -2\\ 0 & -1 & 7 - (a^2 + 1) & -7 - 3a}$$

-1*line 2 + line 1

$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 4 & -5\\ 0 & 1 & 3 & -2\\ 0 & -1 & 7 - (a^2 + 1) & -7 - 3a}$$

line 2 + line 3

$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 4 & -5\\ 0 & 1 & 3 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 10 - (a^2 + 1) & -9 - 3a}$$

so we get equation 3

$10-(a^2+1)z=-9-3a$

rearranging,

$$(a^2+1)z=-19-3a \rightarrow$$

$$z=19/a^2+1 - 3a/a^2+1 \rightarrow $$

$$z=(19/a^2+1) - (-3/a+1)$$

$$z=19/a^2 + 1 - (-3/a) +1$$

$$z=19/a^2 + 2 + 3/a$$

multiply all terms by $a$

$$za=19/a + 2a + 3$$

$$za=(39/19)a + 3$$

$$za=3a+3$$

$$z=3+3/a$$

wut?

I am unsure how to properly answer the question, please help stack exchange!

My algebra skills are a little lacking, please point out helpfully where my thinking is wrong.

I can solve for z but what does that prove

Comment: Why don't you use $LaTeX$. It would make your question more readable and you'd get an answer much more quickly.

Comment: Ill give it a go and re post

Comment: @helpmeh You should [edit] this question, not post a new one.

Comment: I've turned one of your monstrosities into a matrix. Please look at what I've done, and do something like it for the others.

Comment: I have added some more latex formatting... Is not 100% complete so please take some time and convert some of your matrix in properly formatted, readable latex. In addition I have taken the liberty of correcting some of your words. Plurals end with s not z...

Comment: Since you have tagged this (linear-algebra) and write about Gaussian elimination, I suppose that $3xy$ in the second equation should be $3y$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Reasonable assumption...

Comment: Once you start "rearranging", there's an error on almost every line. $-19 \neq 19$, $19/(a^2+1) \neq 19/a^2 + 1$, $-(-3/a+1) \neq -(-3/a)+1$, and so forth. Get your algebraic manipulations under control, or they'll get you in trouble on a lot of other questions.

Comment: Where exactly did the 3 in the second row of $\pmatrix{1&1&7&-7\cr2&3&17&-16\cr1&2&a^2+1&3a\cr}$
come from? Look very closely at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have arrived to this (<s>which is followed by some not very reader friendly part, which I am ignoring</s> EDIT: In the meantime, [N. F. Taussig fixed it](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1062990/revisions)):
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&7&-7\\
0&-1&-3&2\\
0&-1&7-(a^2+1)&-7-3a
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&7&-7\\
0&-1&-3&2\\
0&-1&6-a^2&-7-3a
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&7&-7\\
0&-1&-3&2\\
0&0&9-a^2&-9-3a
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&7&-7\\
0&-1&-3&2\\
0&0&(3-a)(3+a)&-3(3+a)
\end{array}\right)
$$

For $a=-3$ you have
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&7&-7\\
0&-1&-3&2\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right)$$
This system has infinitely many solutions.

If $a\ne-3$, you can divide by $a+3$ to get
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&7&-7\\
0&-1&-3&2\\
0&0&3-a&-3
\end{array}\right)
$$
If $a=3$, then it has no solution. (The last equation is $0x+0y+0z=3$.)

For $a\ne3$ you can see that there is only one solution. (Maybe it would be better if I wrote *for $a\ne\pm3$*; just to remind that now we only consider the case when $a\ne-3$ and we got an additional condition $a\ne3$ to get unique solution.)

---

As a sanity check, you can plug $a=3$ in the original system. You can notice that if you subtract the first equation from the second, you get
$$x+2y+10z=-9.$$

For $a=3$ the third equation is
$$x+2y+10z=9.$$
These two equations are clearly incompatible.

Also for $a=-3$ you can see that the third equation becomes
$$x+2y+10z=-9.$$
So in this case the third equation is direct consequence of the first two equations.

---

I will also point out that if I was doing the Gaussian (or Gauss-Jordan) elimination, I would probably start by subtracting the first row from the second, since then I have two very similar rows, which makes things easier).
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 7 &-7 \\
  2 & 3 &17 &-16\\
  1 & 2 &a^2+1& 3a
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 7 &-7 \\
  1 & 2 &10 &-9\\
  1 & 2 &a^2+1& 3a
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 7 &-7 \\
  1 & 2 &10 &-9\\
  0 & 0 &a^2-9& 3a+9
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 7 &-7 \\
  1 & 2 &10 &-9\\
  0 & 0 &(a-3)(a+3)& 3(a+3)
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 7 &-7 \\
  0 & 1 & 3 &-2\\
  0 & 0 &(a-3)(a+3)& 3(a+3)
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Just in time for the exam :)